# Бесконечная прокрутка owl carusel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, карусель

Всем привет! Есть карусель [ссылка на fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/372/) Как сделать бесконечную прокрутку, т.е. сразу после последнего слайда шел первый? Просто `loop:true` не срабатывает..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true,
    lazyLoad: true,
    loop: true
  });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .owl-item > div img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item > div {
  padding: 0px 2px
}
```

```html
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Подключите [Owl Carousel 2](http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/index.html). Там, как я [вижу по документации](http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-options.html), присутствует параметр **loop**, задав которому значение **true**, вы получите желаемый результат.

Comment: @Deonis да, точняк спасибо - опубликовал вверху рабочий вариант

Answer (score 1):

Да, параметр loop отвечает за "замыкание карусели". Т.е. если на экране помещается 5 слайдов, а в наличии всего 3, то loop дополнит клонировав еще 2 в формате 1 2 3 1 2. Для автопрокрутки нужно добавить

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
   navigation: true,
   pagination: true,
   lazyLoad: true,
   loop: true,
   autoPlay:3000, /*автопрокрутка время в мс*/
 });
});
```